# Python environment dependent on Linux module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

## Question:

Can I automate `module load X` when selecting a Python interpreter in VSCode?

## Background:

I'm using VSCode, connected to a Linux host with the **Remote - SSH** extension.

On this host, I have a Python venv, which is dependent on a Linux module - i.e. to use it in a terminal, I would run:

```bash
module load Python_3.X.X
source ~/venvs/myVenv/bin/activate
```

If I omit the `module load` step, I get an `error while loading shared libraries` if I try to run Python.

I'm also using the **Python** VSCode extension for all the nice linting, debugging etc. When I select `myVenv` as the interpreter, however, there is no way to tell it to `module load Python_3.X.X`, and I get the "Invalid Python interpreter" warning below:

[image: Invalid interpreter warning]

If I look at the output, sure enough it gives me the same `error while loading shared libraries`.

Hence the question, is there a way to automate the `module load` step whenever the Python extension attempts to use `myVenv`? After looking around, the best candidate I can find for this is a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks), however I'm struggling to find any details on how I would implement it correctly (i.e. get the task to run before any actions taken by the Python extension).

Comment: Use `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux` to add parameters to the terminal?

Comment: @JialeDu Thanks for the suggestion. As far as I can tell from the [Profiles docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) and some trial and error, they don't support adding commands to the profile setup. I can add a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) with the command in, but can't figure out how to run this task before any Python extension setup.

Comment: If the existing features cannot be satisfied, you can submit a feature request report on vscode [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found a way to do this:

- Add a `.env` file in the workspace top level. (The name and location of this file can be changed in the setting `"python.envFile":"${workspaceFolder}/.env"`)
- Add the required environment variables for your module to this file. I imagine this will depend heavily on the modules used, but in my case this involved:

  - Updating `PATH` with `PATH=/my_new/module_defined/paths:PATH`.
  - Similarly updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `MANPATH` (although I suppose the manuals might not be strictly necessary).
  - Updating `LOADEDMODULES` and `_LMFILES_`.